# How to resolve this error in ASP.NET Web Forms 4.5.2: Invalid postback or callback argument?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am a new ASP.NET Web Forms developer and I am currently using .NET Framework 4.5.2.I have a simple form that includes two textbox controls and two buttons. I am struggling right now with the button click event. When I click on the button, I got the following error and I don't know why.

[image]

I searched on the web and I couldn't find any solution to this. **Could you please help me in this regard?**

For your information, here's my ASP.NET Code:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAdd" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="post-wrapper" class="row">
                <div id="content" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div id="login">
                        <div class="form-wrap">

                            <div role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email" class="control-label">Name</label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNameNew" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="e.g. fire extinguisher"></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="key" class="control-label">Description</label>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescNew" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="e.g. ........."></asp:TextBox>
                                </div>
                                <%--<div class="form-group">
                            <label for="key" class="control-label">ImagePath</label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>--%>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAdd" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
                                    OnClick="lbtnAdd_Click">
                                    <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add</asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCancel" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-default"
                                    OnClick="lbtnCancel_Click">
                            <span class="fa fa-remove"></span> Cancel</asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtnAdd" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtnCancel" EventName="Click" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Are you using a master page? Make sure that you're only using one 'form' tag inside your .aspx files. You might be using nested form tags.

Comment: Yes, I am using it and I only have one form tag. The error is related to EnableValidationEvent attribute. I don't want to disable this feature.

Comment: How about including a ScriptManager control first after the opening form tag?

Comment: It is already there in the MasterPage and I am still getting this error.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you could try it and provide me with your finding.